# How to calculate just one stationary distribution value?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a standard 8*8 chess board.  And I am analyzing the different possible moves that can be taken by various pieces.  I take that there is no other piece on the board except for the Knight, who starts at any one of the 4 corners of the chess board.  Now, I am trying to find the stationary distribution value at the starting square.  This would give me the long run proportion of time spent at the starting square.

We have 64 states (squares) in total.  When worked out, it involves complicated matrix multiplication for several states (squares).  Is there any result that I have to use here that I am missing?  Any insight will be very helpful.  Thank you...

Comment: You can simplify the problem significantly by using the symmetry of the chessboard - at least one reduction is to consider only a 4x4 section including one corner. Moves that would go to a different 4x4 section can instead be thought of as moving to the analogous square in the 4x4 section you're considering. You should get a 16-state process.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee Thank you!  I'll work out the symmetric distribution for the 16-state process.  If I do this, I will get the stationary distribution value at the starting square for a 4*4 chess board.  And then, is it reasonable to conclude that the stationary distribution value at the starting square will be the same in an 8*8 chess board as well?  Thank you very much for any insight...

Comment: I realize that the stationary distribution value at the starting square tells us the long run proportion of time spent at the starting square.  So, the stationary distribution at the starting square should be a function of the size of the board.  Is that correct?

Comment: I didn't mean that the knight is restricted to just a 4x4 board. I mean that the 4x4 board represents the full movements of the knight on an 8x8 board. Each tile in the 4x4 board corresponds to a set of 4 tiles on the full board. The probability you get for the corner tile represents the probability that the knight will end up on any of the four corners. In the long run the four corners are equivalent, so you will need to divide that probability by 4 to get the desired result.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. Thank you very much for explaining this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, let $G=(V,E)$ be a simple, connected graph which is not bipartite. Consider a random walk on $V$, where if you are currently at vertex $v\in V$, your next step is to one of $v$'s neighbors, chosen  uniformly at random. Your knight problem is a special case of this general setup.

These random walks are well-studied. It is well-known that the stationary probability of each vertex is proportional to its degree (see [these notes](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/teach/262/notes/paul/) from a course taught by Fan Chung, specifically [#2: Stable distributions](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Efan/teach/262/notes/paul/9_28_notes.pdf)). That is, the stationary probability of a vertex $v$ is
$$
{\deg v \over 2|E|}.
$$
For your graph, there are $64$ vertices. It turns out there are $168$ edges, which can be shown as follows. Each edge corresponds to two squares which are a knight's move apart. There are four possible slopes for the line connecting two squares which are a knight's move apart; either $\pm 2$, or $\pm 1/2$. By symmetry, there are the same number of edges of each slope, so we can count the edges with a slope of $2$ alone, then multiply by four to get the total. Suppose that $(x,y)$ is the coordinate of the lower left square of an edge of slope $2$, so the square it is joined to is $(x+1,y+2)$. There are $7$ choices for the $x$ coordinate, as you need $1\le x\le 7$. There are $6$ choices for the $y$-coordinate, as you need $1\le y\le 6$. Therefore, there are $7\times 6=42$ edges of slope $2$, which means there are $4\times 42=168$ edges total.

Furthermore, the degree of the corner vertex is $2$. Therefore, the stationary probability of the corner vertex is $$\frac2{2\cdot 168}=\frac1{168}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the links!  In calculating the no. of edges, are the edges equal to the total number of moves possible from every square?  I am stuck at just the one point of how the number of edges is 2*2*7*6.  Thank you again for the insight.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on how to count the number of edges!

Comment: I have a related question here.  If I have a Markov chain that starts with an n * n matrix consisting of all entries being 0. At each step one of the entries is chosen uniformly at random and flipped, (that is, 0 is changed to 1, or 1 is changed to 0).  Now I am trying to find the long run proportion of times the matrix is the identity matrix.  Here we have a total number of 2^(n^2) states.

Comment: Can I use the same argument as seen above here too?  So, the stationary distribution value at the identity state = no. of moves possible from the identity state / total number of moves possible from all states = 1/ 2^(n^2).  Is this argument reasonable ?  But what makes me doubtful is that here, we are not starting from the identity matrix.  Instead, we start at the matrix where all entries are 0.  Does the starting state make a difference in finding the long run proportion of time spent at a given state?  Thanks a lot once again for any insight.

Comment: Since the starting state is different in the new example, I wonder if it relates to the concept of limiting probabilities... If so, would you know how to approach a case of finding long run proportion of time spent at a certain state, given that the chain starts from a different state?

Comment: Yes, the method here applies to to matrix situation. Yes, the proportion of time in the identity is $1/2^{n^2}$. The starting state does not matter, because the Markov chain will converge to its stationary distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.  I have a conceptual doubt and will be grateful for any guidance.  I read that the Markov chain converges to its stationary distribution only if the chain is aperiodic.  Here, the chain starts at the matrix where all entries are 0.  Let's consider a 2*2 matrix example.  To go to the identity state, this matrix requires a multiple of d=2 steps right?  As in, to go from all zeros to the identity state, this matrix requires either 2 steps, or 4 steps, or 6 steps, etc. So does this not mean that the chain is periodic?

Comment: And if it's periodic, then I guess the stationary distribution does not converge(?).  In this case, what approach should I take to find the long run proportion of time in the identity, given that we start at all zeros... I'd be grateful for your help in understanding this please.

Comment: Can you post the matrix question as a [separate question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)? You are correct, there are some subtleties to consider when it comes to periodicity, but the comment section is not a great place for me to explain. Once you post the  question, make another comment here letting me know, and I will answer it

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I will post the matrix question as a separate question now.

Comment: I have now posted the matrix question as a separate question here.  Thank you once again.  Here is the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4788139/how-to-calculate-the-long-run-proportion-of-time-spent-at-a-certain-state-given

Comment: Hello!  I hope you've been doing well!  I've been trying to understand null recurrence, in a follow-up question related to my earlier question above.  I have explained my progress here, along with where I am stuck https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4804013/how-to-prove-null-recurrence-when-there-are-infinitely-many-states  I would be grateful if you could provide any advice or insights.  Thank you so much!