# How to prove null recurrence when there are infinitely many states?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, markov-process

I have a random walk on a chessboard, where each square is a state/vertex.

I understand that the location of pieces on the board describes a Markov chain, and one way to look at this is through a random walk.  So for instance, on a standard $8 \times 8$ chessboard, the movement of a Knight is a random walk.

And the Markov chain described by the Knight’s movement is irreducible.  This is because starting from any square/state, the Knight can reach all other squares/states on the $8 \times 8$ board.

We can also find the stationary distribution for any vertex/square by considering the Knight’s random walk on this connected graph.  This will be:

Stationary distribution at vertex $(v)$ $=$ degree $(v)$ / sum of the degrees of all vertices,

where the degree of $v$ is the number of vertices/squares the Knight can reach in one step, starting from vertex/square $v$.

Now, instead of a finite state space, suppose I have an infinite state space.  So, I am imagining the chessboard to not have any corners or edges, and the board keeps extending indefinitely in all directions.

I am trying to understand the behavior of the Markov chain described by the Knight’s movement here.  We have a random walk in $2$ dimensions with infinitely many states.  And the edges are L-shaped moves of the Knight that connect successive vertices/squares.

Somewhat related to this set up is the result that a simple random walk on $Z^2$ is recurrent.  Now, if we know that the Knight starts from a certain state/square in the infinite chessboard, can we say that the Knight will certainly return to the starting square with probability $1$?  But my issue is that the random walk given by the Knight’s movement is different from a simple random walk on $Z^2$.

Given this, how can we prove that the Knight’s movement is also recurrent in an infinite chessboard?  As I understand, the Knight’s movement is null recurrent, but I would like to prove this.  Any insights would be most helpful.

Comment: Well, start from the definition of null recurrence (which I didn't see mentioned in your post)...